Evaluating Cost Saving Potential Layer1 to Layer2
I am trying to evaluate cost savings when using a Layer 2 Blockchain network compared to Ethereum/Layer1. Currently i do not necessarily make use of L1/2 inter-communication, so just deploying and interacting on one chain would be enough for my evaluation in the first place. My use case is using about 10 smart contracts that need to be deployed first and transact with each other.
My question is twofold:

Contract Deployment cost - how do i find out how much cheaper it gets per layer 2 network? I don't want to try it out the hard way with all options, although i would start the comparison with probably Optimisim, Base and Arbitrum as of layer2beat rating. Also, I'm not sure, if there is any benefit in deployment cost reduction at all?

Transaction cost - once deployed to the network, how can i compare L1 to L2 costs?


I would go on with the following:
create a hardhat project configuring L1 and L2 deployment and test/scripts to interact with the respective blockchain networks. This is quite some task in my case since i need to upgrade the contracts to specific versions first.
is there a more convenient way to compare perspective L2 cost saving potential? How would you go about it.

In this post, I’ve provided transactions having exactly similar specs being done on L1 & L2. So, by inspecting them, you might get a better understanding of the comparison in terms of transaction fee.

thanks, that points in the same direction
